# Can I inherit access modifiers from super class in Scala?

Tags: scala, protected

Suppose I have the following trait and class extending that trait

```
trait T { protected def f() }

class C extends T { def f(): println("!") }

object Main extends App {
    val c = new C
    c.f() // should be a compile error
}
```

I declared `f` as `protected` in the declaration for `T` so that it can be called from inside the scope of `C`, but not by others. In other words, `C.f()` should be a compile error. I thought the `protected` modifier from `T` would carry over, but it doesn't.

I could just redeclare `C.f()` as `protected` in the declaration for `C`, but I'd rather not have to repeat myself. Is there any other way to do this in Scala?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer: no.

Not specifying an access modifier does not mean "inherit access modifier", it means "public". Scala has no `public` keyword and if it didn't work like this, there would be no way to actually make a protected member public when overriding.

In other words, you have to repeat the `protected` modifier.

Answer (score 2):

I join to `ghik`'s answer and want to add something more.

If you have a `trait T { protected def f() }` then your extending classes may have `f()` declared as `def f()` (which means `public` as `ghik` said) or `protected def f()`, but not `private def f()`.

The general rule is **you cannot change the access type to a more restrictive one**, you can only widen it, so if you'd have a simple `def f()` in your trait, the class couldn't even declare it as `protected`